# wamp error : Could not execute menu item for phpmyadmin

Tags: wampserver

I did this solution

```
Here notepad will open ...

scroll down and you will see the port number that WAMP server takes ...
change that port number to:

#Listen x.x.x.x:8080
Listen 8080
save that file and restart the services... it will work fine...

now check by typing http://localhost:8080/.
```

but it don't solve the problem when i launch phpmyadmin, strangely the localhost is working! https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEbSS.png

Comment: Do you have Skype on your PC?

Comment: Did you install the correct version (64/32 bit)?

Comment: @anog it matter when I dont launch it?

Comment: is the icon showing green? delete skype from the notification icon bar!

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you put Apache back onto port 80.

Your problems may be that you are missing a MSVC runtime dll. Check you have the following installed

```
The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager
The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on version of Apache )
The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on version of Apache )
```

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

If you are using WampServer 2.4
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) and select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMP 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582) Yes you need the x86 Package regardless

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

If you are using WampServer 2.4

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) and select vcredist_x64.exe